# Apple watch's gyroscope.available always return false

Tags: watchos-2

I'm able to get accelerometer data from Apple watch, but I'm unable to get gyroscope and magnetometer data. `gyroscope.available` always return false. Has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of watchOS 2, while the core motion API's exist the gyroscope and magnetometer are not available. There is no way around what you are seeing. Developers currently only have access to the accelerometer.